# App crashes after button press

Tags: android, build, android-studio-2.3

When I'm debugging my app all works, but when I build APK (Debug, release, signed..) it crashes after I press the button.

My onClick method:

```
protected void Click(View V) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Hi!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Button XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSpy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick="Click"
    android:text="Activate"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="212dp" />
```

EDIT:
Sorry forgot to change Spy to Click

Comment: A stacktrace from the crash might be useful. In short there isn't enough info here to help you.

Comment: Compare your method names in xml and in Java. And, yes, please post stacktraces from your crashes when you need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change `protected` to `public` and change `onClick="Spy"` to `onClick="Click"`

Comment: Just mark it as accepted if it works for you

Comment: How does this solve the problem?

Comment: Method referenced in xml onClick must be public

Comment: And this will fix it?

Comment: Yes. My students have made this mistake several times. And Yes, it fixes it. Try it out...

Comment: I think you're missing something...

Comment: And what would that be?

Comment: The method name

Comment: Ouch! I didn't see that. Thanks for pointing that out, updated my answer.